# Broken "New Items in Your Inbox" email

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, email-notification

I just got this mail (formatted as it is in my mail client, which is basically displaying the mail like `less` or a text editor would):

```
The following items were added to your Stack Exchange global inbox since you last checked it on 2011-10-01:
                            14m

                            comment
                            Understanding parse_str in phpThanks for your help, but it turned out it had to If you no longer wish to receive daily updates, you may unsubscribe from this email.

_________________________________________________________________________
Questions? Comments? Let us know on our [feedback site][9].

Stack Exchange Inc. 55 Broadway, 26th Floor, NY NY 10006 <3

[7]: {0}
[8]: http://stackauth.com
[9]: http://meta.stackoverflow.com
```

As you can see, the text for each entry looks messed-up, it should read something like:

```
14m  comment Understanding parse_str in php
             Thanks for your help, but it turned out it had to

If you no longer wish to receive daily updates, you may unsubscribe from this email.
```

Also, it looks like nine ate seven, not to mention 1 to 6. The icing on the cake would be *not* including brackets in `[feedback site][9]`. `feedback site[9]` is (imho) clear enough.

Comment: What is your mail client?

Comment: @JeffAtwood Thunderbird, but the problem also shows with `less` as an email client, i.e. when reading the plain text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the next build we'll improve the format a bit, by excluding that erroneous `[7]: {0}` block and improving the overall spacing on the text-plain reduced version.

Comment: The new version doesn't have the `[7]: {0}` anymore, but now cuts off the comment. If possible, the first line should be `3h comment  [Title of the question]` (no indent at start), and the second line should be the whole comment. If nobody cares about text email (or, as called by its proponents, email), can you post the function generating the text so we can propose a patch?

Comment: @phihag - The comment is cut off in both versions, this is a limitation of how things are stored in the inbox (it's a *massive* amount of data we're talking about here, so it'a tailored to the inbox UI, not the email).

Comment: Oh, ok. But please put a newline between title and comment. Can you spot the beginning of the comment: `Rewrite the subdomain to a location?%2 doesn't exist, so you should get an error`

Comment: @phihag - fair enough, there's a newline in there starting with the next build.