# Images broken in Stack Overflow emails

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, email, email-notification

Seems to be related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108177/205508), but I see that it's from 2011, so reporting again.

The images in Stack Overflow notification emails are broken. See the screen shot bellow:

> [image: screencap]

The link to image is:

> `http://stackoverflow.com//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/icon-48.png`

instead of

> `http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/icon-48.png`

My email client is Yahoo!. I forwarded the email to a gMail address and the image is still broken.

Comment: looking into that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Site logos in global notification emails are working again.

Recently we reconfigured some of our CDN resources to scheme relative URL and the code that sends out global inbox notification emails, which uses the same configuration database, did not handle them correctly.

[image: working again]